# how could I propagate feature to end-user crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have nested crates.

1. lib `Crate A`
2. lib `Crate B` using `Crate A`
3. binary `Crate C` using `Crate B`

with following Cargo.toml

```
# CrateA/Cargo.toml
[features]
webgpu = [
    "web-sys", 
    'web-sys/Document',
    'web-sys/Element',
    'web-sys/GpuAdapter', 
    ...
]
```

```
# CrateB/Cargo.toml
[features]
webgpu = ["CrateA/webgpu"]

[dependencies]
CrateA = {path = "../CrateA", default-features = false}
```

```
# CrateC/Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
CrateB = {path = "../CrateB" , features = ["webgpu"], default-features = false}
```

and when I tried to build CrateC, it failed with following error.

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `web_sys::GpuAdapter`
  |
8 | use web_sys::GpuAdapter;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `GpuAdapter` in the root
```

`web_sys::GpuAdapter` is defined in `web-sys` only when `web-sys/GpuAdapter` feature is used.

I had assumed the above Cargo.toml settings are fine with those scenario but it was not.

What can I do for do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self solved.

I just for forgot `--cfg=web_sys_unstable_apis` for build flags.

Comment: Voted to close as this is not reproducible with the code you gave.